# Excel macro to change the field data type string to long

Tags: excel, visual-studio-macros

I have a function which returns value as string.

```
Function Trimcell(cellvalue As varnant) As String
    Trimcell = Replace(CStr(cellvalue), " ", "")
End Function
```

I want to change the data type string to long . Any help.

Comment: What have u tried? All it should take is to change the return type of the function.

Comment: I have a function .. Function Trimcell(cellvalue as varnant) as string. Trimcell = Replace (CStr(cellvalue)," ","") End function

Comment: I need the function should return Long instead of String. If I change string to long in the return data type in the function, throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to this:

```
Function Trimcell(cellvalue As varnant) As Long
    Trimcell = Val(Replace(CStr(cellvalue), " ", ""))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling error - varnant instead of Variant.

A better option than using `Replace` is to use `Val` which removes blanks, tabs, and linefeed characters from a string and returns a `Double`.  It also stops reading the string at the first non-numeric character apart from period (.) which it recognises as the decimal separator.

As you have declared `cellvalue As Variant` you shouldn't need `CStr` either.

```
Function Trimcell2(cellvalue As Variant) As Long

    Trimcell = Val(cellvalue)
End Function
```